# SharePoint "New Task" form

Tags: cognito-forms, sharepoint

Great product so far.  I love the fact that you can connect with SharePoint/Office 365.

Interesting challenge:

When I connect a form to a standard task list, all the standard fields are not completed correctly and the custom ones are completed correctly.

Is there something special about working with the Task Content Type?

Form: https://www.cognitoforms.com/DonnellyLandscapes/NewTask

In SharePoint after submission:

```
Task Name - Blank
Due Date - Blank
% Complete - 50% (huh?)
Description - Blank
Task Status - Pending (huh?  Default is "Not started")
Property Name - works correctly
Email - Works correctly
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a member of the Cognito Forms development team responsible for the SharePoint integration features.

Thank you for the detailed description of the issue. We are able to reproduce this issue and I will work with our development team to discuss a resolution. The underlying issue relates to the SharePoint "internal" field names for fields associated with the built-in content types. For instance, the SharePoint task content type's "Description" field has an internal field name of "Body". In these scenarios, the SharePoint integration does not properly post the Cognito Form data to the field.

I have created a [feature request](https://trello.com/c/Zt1YggsE) on the Cognito Form idea board for this request.

We welcome our users to submit features they would like to see and constantly add and update our idea board with the new features. Our users also have the ability to vote on features they would like to see in the future. This helps give us a guide as to what we should work on in our next and upcoming releases.

I hope you are enjoying using Cognito Forms!

Thank you,
Kevin